# How to get a user's first toot on mastodon (find account age or first tweet)

Tags: mastodon

How can I easily load the very first toot of a given user on mastodon?

I'm trying to figure out when a given mastodon account was first created. I'm scrolling down in their feed, but I think it will take about 350 years for me to reach their first toot by just scrolling on Mastodon's WUI.

Is there an easy (less than 10 clicks) way to just jump to their very first tweet?

Answer (score 3):

I do not believe that there is an easy way to achieve this via the Web UI.

To find out when an account was created, you can use the Mastodon API. Under Preferences -> Development on your Mastodon account, create a new app with read permissions to get a token. Then you can call the API, for example something like this:

```
curl --header "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" https://[YOURINSTANCE]/api/v1/accounts/search\?q\=[ACCOUNTNAME]\&limit\=1 | jq
```

This will return the user object, containing a `created_at` value.

To get the first toot, you could use the API to fetch all of the posts back to the very first one.

Comment: Can you provide in your answer how to get the `$TOKEN` value for the `Authorization` header?

Comment: Sure thing. Editing that.

Comment: I wonder if there might be nontech-savvy users on Mastodon that have no idea about how to use a [command-line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_(computing)) 